# I need for my <a> link tag to show up as a clickable link in my dropdown menu not just show the text value

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net

I want to display a list in a drop down menu and I have the text values in there but they are not clickable. 
right now the markup looks like this

```
$("#newdiv li").append("<li><a>" + data.Locations[i].beerName + "</a></li>")
```

I want the value displayed to be a clickable and a usable menu item instead of just text.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an href attribute to the anchor.

```
$("#newdiv li").append("<li><a href='" + data.Locations[i].beerPage + "'>" + data.Locations[i].beerName + "</a></li>")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. That works great! Is there any way I can access that new variable after it's clicked so I can use it to show just the selected beer locations on the map?